# Photo viewer for Windows that displays shutter speed/aperture/ISO?

Tags: metadata, photo-viewer

Going through my own photos and looking at the exposure setting and composition is a good way of learning.

Is there a photo viewer for Windows that shows you the exposure settings (shutter speed, aperture and ISO)? None of the Window's own photo viewers has that. I have more advanced, full-scale PP editor (Lightroom), but I don't want to run that clunky software just to check out my photos and the exposure settings.

Comment: Useless for your task, but any version since XP should give you that data under right click -> properties. If you have Photoshop Adobe Bridge will as well. But I think others will have a better suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't specify which version of Windows you are using - but, just in case you aren't aware, when you are in windows explorer you can view the "details pane" which will pull quite a lot of the EXIF information out of image files.  This is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpYCb.png) in Windows 8.1, but it's been around in several previous versions (I can't remember exactly when it was first added).  The image preview is not particularly large - but enough to recognise an image.  I then have Picasa Photo Viewer fire up when I double click on the image - but you could have any viewer associated with image files take over at this point.

[image: windows explorer]

Answer (score 4):

With all other answers providing excellent solutions as well, I have been a fan of ACDSee and have found that [XnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/index.php) to be an excellent and free replacement of it. It has support for raw files as well. Although it is not geared around display of exif data and many other things we photographers do.

On the note of raw files, [RawTherapee](http://rawtherapee.com/) is my development tool of choice (because I don't yet feel enough pressure to pay for Adobe software, being a complete amateur at photography). Which obviously has nice development capabilities along with displaying relevant metadata (shutter, aperture, iso) along with the photos in the thumbnail view.

Answer (score 1):

i used your software but it's little hard to use for photo viewers and editing easily. Download 
[IrfanView free](http://www.irfanview.com/) it's using more easier than other software I think .

Comment: What software are you referring to when you say "I used your software"  Are you commenting on the original post, or one of the answers?

Answer (score 1):

i believe irfanview is by far the best.
this is what you can do to see various exif info, overlayed:

IF you only want to see a few EXIF values while you browse however, I would suggest you display them on the Status bar at the bottom of the screen. Open Options >Properties/Settings and select the Viewing tab. At the bottom of the dialog box you will see where you can type in "placeholders" for displaying various items of data on the status bar. Click on the Help button beside it to see which placeholders you need to use. You can also add text to identify what they are if you like. 
I think what you will probably want is ...... ISO $E34855 F $E33437 Exposure $E33434

(the default iso tag didn't work for me, i tried $E2 for Nikon's ISO tag, and it worked; canon, others etc. will be different probably.)

for full screen:

Take a close look at the options for showing text in fullscreen mode (Options, Fullscreen/slideshow). You can select specific Exif fields to display, which will let you focus on just a few items of interest while browsing in fullscreen mode

here i used $E2 again and i can see the iso.

Answer (score 0):

one program would be exif viewer: http://www.chip.de/downloads/Exif-Viewer_13014286.html 
 this link is german, but maybe there is a language pack or something. You should google for "windows exif viewer" and i am sure you will find something in your language
 EDIT: as said in comments: take a look at irfanview, i think it might be it for you ( maybe with irfanview plugins )
 or check out http://download.cnet.com/Photoplorer/3000-2192_4-10183254.html
 or : http://www.photo-freeware.net/modernview.php
 or when you still havent found it check out : http://www.photo-freeware.net/ .. here you should find something ;)

Comment: I thought about EXIF viewers, and, their primary purpose being not photo viewing, the viewing window is too small. It defeats the purpose of checking out my photos and self-critiquing.

Comment: you need something like "eye of gnome", that is for linux. but maybe there is something like it for windows too. i will take a look

Comment: take a look at acdsee, but that is not for free. \\ or irfanview plugins. if you dont know irfanview, its quiet popular in germany and i think with irfanview plugins it could do the trick, but i keep searching